# On Android, how can I avoid flicker when calling removeView?

Tags: android, flicker

I have two ImageViews that overlap, and I'm calling removeView() to remove the one in the back.  When I do, I'm seeing flicker - the view being removed is briefly drawn on top of the other view, and then it disappears.

I have tried calling setVisibility(View.GONE) and setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) before the remove, but neither helped.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried hiding it before removing? `yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Can't figure this out....

Comment: did you arrive on any solution on this? stucked on a similar problem.

Comment: No, never got anywhere with this.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem with you. Finally I removed the `removeView()` and just used the  `setVisibility(View.GONE)`. This avoided flicker. But I'm not sure whether `setVisibility(View.GONE)` equals `removeView()`. Attach the docs:

> setVisibility(View.GONE):
>    This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>    purposes

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple workaround, which first hides the view by `View.Gone`, then removes it completely to save memory **after a delay**.

```
v.visibility = View.GONE
val handler =  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
handler.postDelayed({
    if(v.parent != null)
        wm.removeView(v)
    }, 300)
```

If you're creating a new View object everytime, this method is ok; but if you're going to add the previously created view again later (same reference), you'll then need to be careful because the view may not have been removed yet (calling `addView` will give error if that's the case). Maybe you can first stop the handler (by making handler global and calling `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`)and then check `v.parent != null` to use `addView` or `updateView`.